# iptables filter before DNAT to act as a firewall

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I am trying to use iptables in a single system to act as a firewall to filter packets and pass vaild packets to servers behind that firewall, but if I use DNAT, the data will pass to the servers directly and not filtered.

What should I do to achieve that?

Comment: You obviously filter the packets _before_ you forward them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even DNATed packet are going through the filter. It is processed in the order

```
NAT-PREROUTING (e.g. DNAT) => FORWARD => NAT-POSTROUTING (e.g. SNAT, MASQUERADE)
```

In case it is not working for you the most probably it is because you have forward rules based on the headers valid before DNAT. Once the DNAT is done for the forwarding processing it is processed with already changed destination.

In case you would provide more details on the rules and the information which traffic "is not filtered" somebody can try to check your case... You have provided too load amount of information to be able to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the diagram on this page](https://www.booleanworld.com/depth-guide-iptables-linux-firewall/). It illustrates how NAT rules come before the FORWARD rules. Even though you DNAT to some host behind the firewall, the packet still passes through the FORWARD (and POSTROUTING) rules before actually being sent to the host.

You can do your filtering in the FORWARD rules. Also helpful in debugging your rules is to insert something like this FORWARD which will log to the syslog:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -j LOG --log-prefix="FWD: "
```

It will create a lot of entries in syslog but gives you some idea what traffic is being passed. Once you have things set up, just remove the rule.